# Is didReceiveResponse guaranteed to precede connectionDidFinishLoading?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

**Background:** During the handshake process, my iOS app *learns* the server capabilities by

1. Checking its header information in `didReceiveResponse`

   **AND**
2. Parsing its response XML in `connectionDidFinishLoading`

**Problem statement**: Since callback #1 precedes #2, I am storing the version string in `didReceiveResponse` and checking it later in `connectionDidFinishLoading` when the response is available.

This fortunately works fine so far because #1 preceeds #2. But is that order always guaranteed by network / iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> Zero or more connection:didReceiveResponse: messages will be sent to the delegate before receiving a connection:didReceiveData: message. The only case where connection:didReceiveResponse: is not sent to a delegate is when the protocol implementation encounters an error before a response could be created.
>   Zero or more connection:didReceiveData: messages will be sent before any of the following messages are sent to the delegate: connection:willCacheResponse:, connectionDidFinishLoading:, connection:didFailWithError:.

So unless there's an error, you can guarantee that you'll get a didReceiveResponse before getting a connectionDidFinishLoading.

Comment: This may be a lame question but what constitutes an error before the response is created:

> The only case where this message is not sent to the delegate is when the protocol implementation encounters an error before a response could be created

Answer (score 3):

From [NSURLCOnnection Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> ```
> Zero or more connection:didReceiveResponse: messages will be sent
> ```
>
> to the delegate before receiving a connection:didReceiveData: message.
>   The only case where connection:didReceiveResponse: is not sent to a
>   delegate is when the protocol implementation encounters an error
>   before a response could be created.
>
> ```
> Zero or more connection:didReceiveData: messages will be sent
> ```
>
> before any of the following messages are sent to the delegate:
>   connection:willCacheResponse:, connectionDidFinishLoading:,
>   connection:didFailWithError:.
>
> ```
> Zero or one connection:willCacheResponse: messages will be sent to
> ```
>
> the delegate after connection:didReceiveData: is sent but before a
>   connectionDidFinishLoading: message is sent.

So, it will not happen ONLY if there is an error before creating the response.

Comment: Why do you repeat @Malcolm Box answer?

Comment: I appreciate your concern Nekto, but I did not intentionally do so. I would suppose we posted the answers at a similar time.

Comment: I do maintain I did not copy off the answer or anything Nekto, I looked into and verified my references myself. If there is any concern, I do encourage @Saptarshi Biswas to mark Malcolm Box 's answer as the correct one. Wouldn't want to create bad blood on anyone's part.

Comment: @madhumal-gunetileke: +1 Thanks for your answer.
I'm pretty sure this was a case of overlapping posts; happens all the time!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. In `didReceiveResponse` you could check `NSURLResponse` and if something will be incorrect you can just stop downloading. So `connectionDidFinishLoading` will be called only after you've checked the response.